# ASP.NET Double-postbacks - the always-fun question

Tags: asp.net, postback

I know the general guidelines to double-postbacks, but this one is driving me **nuts**. It's a button onclick. C#. ASP.NET 2.0. And it's **intermittently** posting back twice when I click it in production. Can't replicate from staging, at least on the scale I've tried so far.

The code hasn't changed since before it starting doing this, as far as I can tell, and the flow of the logic certainly doesn't call for a double-dip into the click code at random times. I'm starting to dive into network traces (there are some duplicate acks and dropped segments, to be fair) and wondering if I should nuke the Temporary ASP.NET folder.

Also eyeballing this jQuery modal popup .click(function()  call that returns true. Something in the back of my Javascript brain makes me suspicious.

And [this interesting bug](http://ddkonline.blogspot.com/2008/02/aspnet-double-postback-bug-strikes.html) that has to do with blank img sources.

Comment: IE, so far. The Javascript path I just recently wandered down, so I'll start hacking at others now. Chrome's up next.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've only seen this problem pop up when a button click calls javascript that manually calls form.submit() but does not correctly cancel the click event, and thus it posts twice.

I'm not sure but I believe that if that's the case, one postback will include ButtonID=ButtonID and one will not.

Comment: Good suggestion, I'll start looking at the click code more carefully.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you are not handling the even on other Events too, like Page load, Page Init

Answer (score 0):

And make sure you don't cause double-postback yourself in handling onsubmit event on form tag the wrong way. Like:

```
function Loading() {
  $('*').css('cursor','wait'); // To change cursor while waiting for postback
  document.forms[0].submit();  // Cause postback (maybe 2nd time if already fired by Button).
}

<form id="form1" runat="server" onsubmit="Loading();">
```